# Getting 400 error when closing Excel session using the MS Graph API

Tags: session, microsoft-graph-api

I've created a microservice that takes in a workbook and a set of values. The microservice creates a non-persistent session for the workbook, sets some named ranges to the values, and returns contents of a different set of named ranges.

When I try to clean up the non-persistent session, I get a 400 error.

edit:
My question is "Are non-persistent sessions 'closable'?"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're question is missing details (code your using, traces of calls, detailed error contents, etc) the community would need to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The non-persistent session is also closable. I'm guessing you are including the HTTP header as shown [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/workbook_closesession.md).

You could also ignore this error for the time-being. Session close error shouldn't result in application level error for the end-user. There is no side effect for the app - it just means that Excel has a bunch of unclosed sessions till it times out. We will take a look on the server side.

Comment: Yeah, we're using the official javascript client and are passing session id header consistently across all of our calls to the api, so it was weird that we were getting errors when closing sessions. My only concern with leaving a bunch of open sessions is whether those will affect our throttling limits in any way.

Comment: The throttling shouldn't be affected by number of sessions on the server. I can warn you that some of the HTTP  `429` error code you get for Excel REST are not related to actual throttling but due to a bug that is wrongly classifying the error to be `429`. I suggest re-try if you do get throttling error with some backoff logic to allow server to recover from error state.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've been getting 429 responses that are missing the `Retry After` header - maybe those are the ones I caused by the bug? Do you have any suggestions on the backoff timing? Right now, we're waiting 100ms when we get any error.

Comment: You are right. The `retry-after` headers are missing for all 429s. 100ms seems quite low. We already wait for 10s before sending error message anyway. Waiting just 100ms more won't help I think. Perhaps start with 1s, then 3s, 5s, 10s and so on. I don't know if your app can actually function with this kind of delay in user experience though...